# C# - Where is the NuGet package for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Security?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have an azure function in visual studio 2022 from where I am trying to reference Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Security. However, I get the error - `The type/namespace "Security" does not exist in "Microsoft.WindowsAzure"`.

Could you please help here? Which package do we need to reference to fix this? Is this supported in azure function or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the package through the NuGet package manager which is under

tools >> NuGet package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for Solutions

Search for the required packages and then reference it on the solution.

Also, you can use this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.SDK/) to different ways to get NuGet packages.